# How to apply ORDER to GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the `article` table, each having a related category (or NULL if not categorized - these articles don't interest me in this case).

I want to get 8 newest articles each from one category in a way that there is always only one article for one category (i.e. never 2 articles from the same category).

This query almost work:

```
SELECT article.id, article.title, category_container.title  FROM `article`
JOIN `category_container` ON category_container.id = article.category_id
WHERE `category_id` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `category_id` ORDER BY article.created_at DESC LIMIT 8
```

The problem is, ORDER doesn't work. I want newest, it returns me the earliest ones (with the smallest id, while it should be the opposite).

So, **how to apply ORDER to GROUP BY?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  Your query is broken -- and in the latest versions of MySQL you would properly get an error.

Instead use a *filtering* method to get the latest rows.  Here is a method using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, cc.title
FROM article a JOIN
     category_container cc
     ON cc.id = a.category_id
WHERE a.created_at = (SELECT MAX(a2.created_at)
                      FROM article a2
                      WHERE a2.category_id = a.category_id
                     )
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

For performance, you want an index on `article(category_id, created_at)`.

In the more recent versions, this would be even simpler using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, cc.title
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.category_id ORDER BY a.created_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM article a
     ) a JOIN
     category_container cc
     ON cc.id = a.category_id
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Given that your query runs with no errors, you are probably using an older version of MySQL and this won't work.

Comment: Thanks. ORDER BY is not necessery in the first query then, I guess; it also assumes that I don't have two articles with the same exact time... maybe id would be better to compare then, I suppose. BTW where does the downvote comes from?